# How do I get the input consumed by a parser in Parsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, compiler-construction, parsec

**TL;DR**: Is there a simple way for me to get the input stream consumed by a parser? Perhaps there is a way using the `getInput`, `getPosition`, and `parsecMap` utilities provided by parsec?

I have a lexer that parses a list of tokens. Each of these tokens are a parse tree ADT. I need to convert some of the tokens back into the stream that was consumed when I parsed the token. However, I would like to avoid writing tons of code to deconstruct the parse trees. I also do not want to change the code of every parser, only the top level ones (I am using recursive descent.)

I want a simple way to get the portion of a stream that is consumed by a parser. In case it matters, I am parsing `Char` tokens from a `String` (or `[Char]`, however you prefer). I tried to find a combinator in the [parsec documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.16.1) for this purpose, but I found none. I know I could change all of the parsers to return the strings they consume and the parse tree in a tuple, but I would rather not rewrite all of those parsers.

Is there a simple way for me to get the input stream consumed by a parser? Perhaps there is a way using the `getInput`, `getPosition`, and `parsecMap` utilities provided by parsec?

Thank you for reading this far! Let me know if I need to clarify or give more details. Cheers!

Comment: Perhaps you can use [`lookAhead`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.16.1/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:lookAhead)

Comment: @4castle Could you elaborate on how that would help me get the stream consumed by a parser?

Comment: In other words, an equivalent of [`Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.gather`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html)? This isn’t a complete answer, but I suppose you could use `getInput` before and after, and diff them (roughly, `stripSuffix after before`), or use an underlying monad `m` that records which characters are consumed. Depending on your reason for wanting this, there may well be a better way of addressing that need.

Comment: @JonPurdy Yes, thank you! A Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP.gather equivalent is what I am looking for. And yes, the stripSuffix solution you mentioned is what I had in mind when I mentioned getInput in the question. Thank you for making that more concrete. Honestly, I do not understand what the underlying monad is, but I will get back to you on that idea. Thank you, Jon!

Comment: @JonPurdy The stripSuffix solution is good enough for me, right now. I did some reading and tinkering to better understand the underlying monad. I think that is a very good idea. I may come back to that solution, if I find the stripSuffix solution to be under-performing. However, the stripSuffix solution was simple and easy for me to implement. Thank you again! I plan to eventually share my implementation as an answer to this question, unless you or someone else does the honors. Cheers!

Comment: @PeterBergman: Glad to help! Incidentally I noticed yesterday that Megaparsec has a [`match`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.3.1/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#v:match) function for this.